# how convert string variable to datetime variable in sql-server?

Tags: t-sql, datetime, varchar

I'm relatively new to sql-server; I'm trying to have a start-date and end-date pulled from a form-variable as string then convert it into datetime (yyyy-mm-dd) format and I can't seem to find anything that works. Attempted code and resulting error is below. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
declare @startdate as varchar
declare @enddate as varchar
set @startdate=cast(@startdate as datetime)
set @enddate=cast(@enddate as datetime)

SELECT order_date, inv_no 
from invoices 
where order_date between @startdate and @enddate
```

The error I keep getting is:

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to specify a length for your variables to begin with to stop them being truncated to 1 character. Also `yyyy-mm-dd` doesn't work on all locales for `datetime`. `yyyymmdd` is more robust.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 2):

specify a length for your `varchar`:

```
declare @startdate as varchar(10)
declare @enddate as varchar(10)
set @startdate=cast(@startdate as datetime)
set @enddate=cast(@enddate as datetime)

SELECT order_date, inv_no 
from invoices 
where order_date between @startdate and @enddate
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to cast necessarily

```
declare @startdate varchar(50)
declare @enddate varchar(50)
declare @start datetime = @startdate, @end datetime = @enddate
select @start, @end
```