# How to set value on varchar to datetime variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two variables, one is `varchar` another one is `datetime`. I need to convert `varchar` to `datetime`

```
declare @startdate as varchar(10)= '1/1/2013 1:60AM'
declare @enddate as varchar(10)= '1/1/2014 1:60AM'
declare @startdTime datetime

set @ startdTime =cast(@startdate as datetime)
```

This conversion however causes an error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

How to convert this without error? I see several example on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862003/how-convert-string-variable-to-datetime-variable-in-sql-server) but fail to get solution,need help on this issue.

IF have any query please ask, thanks in advance

Comment: First do you see varchar(10) as correct to hold string of 15 length?

Comment: almas shaikh thanks for reply,instead of varchar(10) i use varchar(max) but get same error.

Comment: If you had declared `@startdate` and `@enddate` as `DATE` from the beginning, you wouldn't even need to convert anything..... please: always use the **most appropriate** datatype! If you're dealing with dates - use `DATE` (not `VARCHAR(10)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your input string **1:60AM** to **1:06AM**

```
declare @startdate as varchar(20)= '1/1/2013 1:06AM'
declare @enddate as varchar(20)= '1/1/2014 1:06AM'
declare @startdTime datetime

SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(20), @startdate ,101) 
SELECT CAST(CONVERT( VARCHAR(30), @startdate ,101) AS DATETIME)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

make Sure about time . is it 1.60AM

```
declare @startdate as varchar(50)= '01/01/2013 1:00 AM'
declare @enddate as varchar(50)= '01/01/2014 1:00 AM'
declare @startdTime datetime

set @startdTime =cast(@startdate as datetime)
print @startdTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `'1/1/2013 01:60 AM'` is more than 10 character. Increase it to 20 or more

Like

```
@startdate AS VARCHAR(25)
@enddate AS VARCHAR(25)
```

**N:B:**

```
 There is nothing like '1:60 AM',Make it "2:00 AM" or "1:06 AM"
```

Comment: Anik Islam Abhi,thanks for reply .i use varchar(max) instead of varchar(10) but get the same error.

Comment: Why my answer got negative vote ?? what's wrong in it ?

Answer (score 0):

Different type of Date time formats for MS SQL